# Adding Followers to mail_followers widget automatically from hr.employee in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

i'm writing a ticketing module and i need the assigned employee to a specific ticket to be automatically follow the ticket the thing as is it followers are added form res.partner model and i need to add them from hr.employee and res.partner

here is my work around

python:

```
class ticket(models.Model):

   _name = 'itmangement.ticket'

   _description = 'IT Ticket Management Process'

   _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

   #some other fields

   assigned_to_id = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string="Assigned To")

   employee_message_follower_ids=fields.Many2many('hr.employee')

   @api.one

   def action_assign(self):

         self.employee_message_follower_ids =[(6,0,self.assigned_to_id.ids)]
```

and the view:

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>                  
<div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="employee_message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each Employee, Related User will be there. For each Related User, Partner shall be Created and Once you assign a Ticket to an Employee, immediately he will be added as Follower. if its not adding then, you can add like this,

```
self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'message_follower_ids':[(4, partner_id)]})
```

Comment: <br/> well mail_follower widget only adds partners when i try to add followers and the  code you just wrote i don't have a partner_id field in  my model or the inherted model ['mail.thread']

Comment: Don't have Related user for each employee?

Answer (score 0):

Since message_follower_ids contain the mail.follower objects' ids, and not the partner_ids themselves, you need a method to add the follower(s). Something like this:

```
def add_follower_id(self, res_id, partner_id, model):
    followers_obj = self.env['mail.followers']
    follower_id = False
    reg = {
        'res_id': res_id,
        'res_model': model,
        'partner_id': partner_id, }
    try:
        follower_id = followers_obj.create(reg)
    except:
        _logger.info(u'AddFollower: follower already exists')
    return follower_id
```

where res_id is the id of your object
model is the model of your object ('crm.lead' for example).
and partner_id is the id of the partner who is going to be the follower (not de object, but the id instead). If you pass the object you will get a "can't adapt type" exception.

Perhaps there is a better solution, (a previous existing method to do this) but I did not find it, and this worked for me.